# Activites not showing up in Follower Feed

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I was facing some really weird issue. 
1) I have Feed1 (Flat Feed) and Feed2(Notification)
2) Feed2 follows Feed1
3) Activity1 added to Feed1, shows in Feed1 but does not show up in Feed2. Not even in Data Explorer

This worked fine for last 2 days, suddenly stopped working couple of hours back. In desperate measure, I recreated the Feed Groups Feed1 and Feed2 from Dashboard and the issue was fixed.

I am concerned that this is test configuration and I could do this.  What could have been done in production. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: probably better if you share more information with support@getstream directly. SO questions are more suitable for general purpose questions (eg. how do I build X with Stream and alike)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have done the same.

Comment: better to close it then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is a specific case which should be dealt separately with the Getstream team. I have followed the recommendation and send them additional details over their support channel.